# Como eu rodo uma função ou método específico através de um script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

No NodeJs nós temos a possibilidade de personalizarmos nossos scripts no *package.json* e rodá-los por meio do *npm run [nome_do_script]*.

Porém, eu gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de rodar uma função específica do arquivo JS ou TS. Tipo, eu tenho o arquivo ***aquivo.js***:

```
export funcao1 = ( ) => {console.log('Você rodou a função 1')}
export funcao2 = ( ) => {console.log('Você rodou a função 2')}
```

Dessa forma, eu queria saber se eu teria que criar um script para cada função ou tem alguma opção de especificar qual função eu poderia rodar.

Comment: Diretamente, não (pelo menos não tinha, pode ter mudado). Se procurar um pacote no NPM que faça isso, talvez ache. De qualquer forma você pode criar um arquivo que chame a `funcao1` e outro que chame a `funcao2` ou passar um parâmetro pro JavaScript que verificará o valor pra executar uma das funções

Answer (score 1):

Você pode rodar um eval no seu package.json scripts, para chamar uma função especifica de seu arquivo, ex:

```js
const init = function() {
   console.log('hi');
};

const end = function() {
   console.log('bye');
};

module.exports = { init, end }
```

Em seu arquivo package.json, para chamar diferentes funções vc pode fazer assim:

```js
scripts: {
  start: "node -e 'require("caminho para arquivo js").init()'",
  end: "node -e 'require("caminho para arquivo js").end()'"
}
```

Não sei até aonde isso é uma pratica ruim, mas para fins de teste, e execução local acredito que não exista problema.